Powerbi: Exporting data from a visual object Table of 500K rows to csv file
I'm having trouble exporting data from a Table (visual object) in Powerbi to a csv/Excel file.
This table contains a lot of rows (around 500k) and I can't directy export it into a csv file.
I also tried using Power Automate for Powerbi but it has a limit of 100k rows.
Does anyone know how to overcome this limit or any other solutions? Perhaps using a Python script?
Thank you very much!
